# Regular Expressions Exclude From a class

Tags: regex

I'm building a dynamic code generator and using regular expressions.
Given this block of text

```
##Properties
                            public #PropertyType# #NewProperty#
                            {
                                get; set;
                            }
##
##Events
                            public event #EventName#-#EventExt#;
##
                            }
                            #endregion
```

I want to be able to extract to blocks of text, namely:

```
##Properties
                            public #PropertyType# #NewProperty#
                            {
                                get; set;
                            }
##
```

and

```
##Properties
                            public #PropertyType# #NewProperty#
                            {
                                get; set;
                            }
##
```

I've been trying to use this `##[\S\s]+##` as my expression but it's taking both and joining them into one. So I was wondering if there was a way to exclude the "##" characters from the [\S\s] class so that it doesn't get recognized. Is there such a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using lazy on your regular expression:

`##[\S\s]+?##`

This will match as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
##(?:[^#]|#(?!#))+##
```